# Regex : Phone number starting with 06 or 07

Tags: javascript, regex, digit

I have this function which works only for 10 digits.

```
function telValide( tel )
{
    var reg = new RegExp('^[0-9]{10}$', 'i');
    return reg.test(tel);
}
```

I would like to check phone number starting with `06` or `07`.

Ex :

**06** 01010101 : true

**07** 01240101 : true

**00** 04343000 : false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var reg = new RegExp('^((06)|(07))[0-9]{8}$', 'i');
```

Comment: The first `[ ]` is going to make a character set that matches one of `(`, `0`, `6`, `|`, `0`, `7`, or `)`. Plug it into http://www.regexper.com/.

Comment: The first character set is broken.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's a simple case:

```
^0[67][0-9]{8}$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
'^0(6|7) [0-9]{8}$'
```

Or if you mean you want the numbers without a space:

```
'^0(6|7)[0-9]{8}$'
```

Check out some excellent regex tutorials [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html&ei=jLL_Uf_-MYXXiAK284HIAQ&usg=AFQjCNEi0GPwTIIpInTqQDV_5xK1ozYsAg&sig2=r2EmKhJlgCZO4d72wFjrXw) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions&ei=vbL_UbGtK7H2igKlEg&usg=AFQjCNG7-PfWq3NHKvL8n3yhnVwzrC6oAQ&sig2=-iPq97F0GCOPd-bhvhSQYw).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest pattern would probably be

```
^0[67]\d{8}$
```

i.e.

- 0
- 6 or 7
- a digit
- repeated exactly eight times

That assumes that your white space is merely for emphasis.

You could also be fancy and use a lookahead

```
^(?=0[67])\d{10}+$
```

This isn't really adding much expect complexity however.

Answer (score 0):

Try it  `/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/`  and for more details check below links help you how validate your phone and defined specific format

http://www.zparacha.com/phone_number_regex/

http://dzone.com/snippets/regular-expression-validate